# Can Vertex Groups be preserved in the result of a Boolean modifier?

Tags: modifiers, vertex-groups

The answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/86978/35559) (which I believe is outdated, anyway), covers preserving vertex groups on a modified object **A** after it has been combined with a target object **B**, by using a *Boolean* on **A**'s modifier stack.

But I am interested in any way that **B**'s vertex weights can be used to influence modifiers further down  **A**'s stack. I've tried all sorts of ways of shuffling weights around within **A** with *Vertex Weight Edit* and *Vertex Weight Mix*, and transferring between  **B** and **A** using *Data Transfer*, with no luck, yet.

A use-case might be to smooth the junction in  a Boolean Union of **A** and **B**.

**A** and **B** could both have *Vertex Weight Proximity* modifiers, targeted on one another. Then after the Boolean, the combined weights could be used to control a *Smooth* modifier in the now-combined **A**, biasing it to the points where the meshes meet.

(It would be very nice if, when meshes were combined by a *Boolean*, their weights came along for the ride, and were added to **A**'s list of vertex-groups)

Comment: You can, following the link you gave.  It sounds like the part that you're missing is that you need to be copying vertex groups (via data transfer) from *an unmodified duplicate* of the mesh on which you wish to restore VGs.  There's not just A and B (which can't DT from each other because loop), but also A'.

Comment: Hi, @Nathan, thanks... I'll try again... I'm not getting anything from B into A to use further down A's stack. Can this keep the Boolean live?

Comment: Yes, it can keep the boolean live.  It's not good for your use case of smooth though, because of the boolean topology.

Comment: Ahh, OK, maybe a different case. I know the mods in A and B can survive from the independent meshes, but I want the weights to influence mods to  the _combined_ mesh.